# How to dynamically create UI elements (journal entries) in Unity3D at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm making a journal app in Unity (C#) and I can't for the life of me figure out how to properly generate the UI (at runtime) of all the journal entries and have it scrollable within a viewport.

So far I've been able to :

- generate an empty UI game object "Entry",
- parent it to UI game object "Entries",
- create a TextMeshPro component in Entry,
- concatenate all entries into a string and show the text

But the size of the TextMeshPro component is huge and doesn't fit in the game window, and using scroll rect doesn't allow me to go to both extremes, [as can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIwlG.png)

This is the code I wrote to create the UI and show the journal text:

```
public class ShowEntries : MonoBehaviour
{
    TextMeshProUGUI text;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject entry = new GameObject();
        entry.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        entry.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, -1000);
        entry.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        entry.AddComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        text = entry.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        text.rectTransform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        text.alignment = TextAlignmentOptions.Center;
        text.color = Color.white;
        text.fontSize = 0.5f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        DrawEntries();
    }

    public void DrawEntries()
    {
        string textFull = "";
        foreach (Experience experience in Global.experienceList)
        {
            textFull += experience.Format();
        }
        text.text = textFull;
    }
}
```

I feel like there is a more elegant approach to displaying n number of journal entries in the UI canvas but am fairly new to C# so just wanted to post of here to see if I could get some tips. Ideally, it would generate a list of UI buttons (one for each entry) with a preview, that when clicked opens the entire entry, but for now I'm just trying to figure out how to display the text properly.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! By creating a UI element prefab I was able to instantiate all the journal entries and set the correct values.